# What is explicit generation in IBM ESQL?

Tags: websphere, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

IBM documentation of the LIST constructor function contains the following sentence: "The LIST constructor complex function is used to explicitly generate lists of values that can be assigned to fields in an output message".

What does the term "explicitly generate" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this topic in the IBM docs for IBM Integration Bus:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=functions-list-constructor-function.

You may find it useful to read this topic as well: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/10.0?topic=functions-row-list-comparisons

In previous versions of IIB/WMB a 'list' was an internal data type (some built-in functions would return a list), but the ESQL programmer could not declare a list or construct a list using their own code.

So to answer your question...I think the phrase 'explicitly generate' is highlighting the fact that it is *now* possible for a programmer to declare and initialise a *literal* list of values, and work with that list in their ESQL code.